# Is there a way to access a React component's state when importing in a different file (as a library)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, state

I have a React component with state in it:

```
export const Toggle = ({initalValue, theme, ...otherProps}) => {

    const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(initalValue)
    const toggleProps = {
        initalValue: initalValue,
        theme: theme
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsToggle(!isToggle)
    }

    return (
        <StyledToggle isToggle={isToggle} {...toggleProps}{...otherProps} onClick={handleClick}>

        </StyledToggle>
    )

}
```

I import this component in a different file:

```
import {Toggle} from 'something'

//

<Toggle />
```

Is there a way to access the `isToggle` state in the other file. And if it's not possible, is there any alternative to do that?

Comment: use redux or context api.

Comment: The point of the component state is that it is private to the component. If it should be modified by something else, then it should be a prop instead (which react-redux does, for instance).

Comment: I was a bit unclear. I meant if as if it's a library. Then how?

Comment: So `Toggle` comes from a library? Which one is it?

Comment: My library, I’m importing my own component in a different file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the isToggle state in the other file.

That is an anti-pattern.

An alternative is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and put `isToggle` in the parent component.
`setIsToggle` can then be passed as a prop to `<Toggle/>`.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(initalValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [isToggle]);

  return (
    <Toggle setToggle={setIsToggle} />
  );
}
```

Comment: You could explain why it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: But what if it's a library of components? (that's what i want)

Comment: If you  wish to access the state of a component's children, you can assign a property called ref to each child. There are  two ways to implement references: Using React.createRef() and callback refs

Comment: @IAMSTR true but [don't overuse refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs). Think of state ownership, for this case it's internal state.

Comment: completely forgot about that  thanks :) @JosephD.